# drawImage within separate jpanel draws just a piece

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm not that familiar with Java and I'm a little clueless about my current problem.
I'm trying to draw an Image within a separate class of my Main JFrame, but it
always draw just a little piece of the picture (maybe 10x10px). 
(A test with a Label worked)

Maybe I didn't used the g.drawImage method correct, or the JPanel don't have enough space??

MainWindow:

```
public class Deconvolutioner extends JFrame {
Draw z;
Picturearea picturearea;

class Draw extends JPanel {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {


    }
}

public Deconvolutioner() {
    setTitle("Deconvolutioner");
    setLocation(30,1);
    setSize(1300,735);
    super.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,11));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);

    this.setLayout(flow);

    picturearea = new Picturearea();

    this.add(picturearea);

    add(z = new Draw());
    setVisible(true);

}

class Open implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser fileOpen = new JFileChooser();
        FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("png & jpg files", "png",  
        "jpg");
        fileOpen.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
        int returnVal = fileOpen.showDialog(null, "Open file");
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)  {
            try {
                String path = fileOpen.getSelectedFile().getPath();
                URL url = new File(path).toURI().toURL();
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);

                picturearea.setPicture(img);

            } catch (IOException ex)  {
                System.err.println("Some IOException accured (set the right path?): ");
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        } else   {

        }

        repaint();
    }
}
```

And the separate class:

```
public class Picturearea extends JPanel {
  public BufferedImage image;
  Draw z;

  public Picturearea() {
      add(z = new Draw());
      setVisible(true);
  }

class Draw extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);

    }
}

public void setPicture(BufferedImage picture) {
    try  {                
        image = picture;
    }  catch (Exception e)  {
        System.err.println("Some IOException accured (did you set the right path?): ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    repaint();
}

}
```

I'm grateful for every help.
thanks for your time.

Comment: `A test with a Label worked)` - so why are you attempting to reinvent the wheel? When painting an image at its actual size you should just use a JLabel. You should only use custom painting when you need to customize the image. Keep your code simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are using `FlowLayout` for `JFrame`'s `contentPane`'s layout. `FlowLayout` obeys component's `preferredSize`. Try setting `preferredSize` of your `pictureArea` by `pictureArea.setPreferredSize(Dimension)`  or overriding `getPreferredSize(Dimension)` function in `PictureArea` class.
- you are using `paint(Graphics g)` for custom painting:

  ```
  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
      g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);

  }
  ```

  Do not override `paint()` for custom painting override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` instead. And You may need to scale your image to fit in the size of the JPanel. you can use `g.drawImage(x, y, width, height, observer)` function if you need to scale your image.

  ```
  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);

  }
  ```